# Attribute Error using the webbrowser module

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I wrote this simple code and saved it as a .py file:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://school.bighistoryproject.com/bhplive')
```

However when I run it I get the following error:

**AttributeError: partially initialized module 'webbrowser' has no attribute 'open' (most likely due to a circular import)**

I know the code technically works because if I type each line individually in the Shell it works!
What is going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If your file is named `webbrowser.py` that will cause an `AttributeError` because it tries to import your file, instead of the module.